# How to use HTTPS requests in JavaScript - Express

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, https, request

I'm developing an application using **Express** for my server and **React** for the client-side.

Each request was made by a `fetch` call and everything worked fine, untill I got into Facebook Login which now requires an **HTTPS** protocol.

This is what I've done so far:

- create a .key
- create a .get self-signed certified
- import everything in express using the https package
- enable https when starting my client

The problem is that there seems to be no way to use `Fetch()` with **HTTPS**.

The request is never sent to the server and I get a `CORS error` (that was not happening in **HTTP**)

Can I somehow keep using Fetch calls? 
Otherwise, how can I manage HTTPS requests in JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

The exact error I'm facing is:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘https://localhost:3001/api/signUp’.
(Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

Moreover, for those who are wondering about the context, I'm using fetch to call a POST request to my Express server.js which will manage the Facebook Login by using Passport.
This call needs now a callback route which is only allowed to be in HTTPS, so I'm trying to switch anything in HTTPS.

Comment: Post the error message in its entirety

Comment: Why are you using fetch for facebook login ?!

Comment: I've edited my question with more information.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with HTTPS. OAuth just doesn't work with Ajax.

Comment: @Quentin maybe it was not clear enough in my question: the issue is between my client and my server, which will then perform the OAuth request by other means.